# Selenium screenshot returns blank white image python webdriver

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, debian

I'm running the following script in a debian instance at google cloud platform and it returns me a white blank screenshot.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=500x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('url_here')

driver.save_screenshot('my_screenshot.png')
```

Additional Info:

- Python 3.7.3
- Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74
- ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51
- selenium==4.1.3

Comment: Try it without headless.

Comment: If the page is built with a lot of dynamic Javascript, `driver.get` might return before the whole page is rendered.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan it's a server, I just have acccess to terminal.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried to wait applying time.sleep(20) and didin't work as well.

Comment: Do you see the conflict here?  In headless mode, it doesn't maintain a screen, so there is no image to get a screenshot of.  You can manage the object model, but there's nothing to see.